# помогите с ошибкой при работе с appium 1.6.0 и Xcode 8

Tags: java, ios

Уже долгое время пытаюсь настроить работу автотестов на iOS + appium

сейчас имею ошибку:

```
[Xcode] Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'


[Xcode] 
Testing failed:
    No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.

[Xcode]     Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
** TEST FAILED **
```

Comment: у нас до сих пор нет тэга 'appium'?!

Answer (score 0):

Решилось переустановкой appium и запуском из нужной директории.